# Retrieve link address from Span Class in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning to code in javascript and jquery so my knowledge is exceptionally poor. Im trying to edit a script(with lots of googling) that was written in tampermonkey by a friend and I assume I havent been able to find the answer through search as I have been using the incorrect terms - but dont know what they are.

this is the HTML

```
<span class="village_anchor contexted" data-player="9281645" data-id="804"> 
<a href="/game.php?village=143&amp;screen=info_village&amp;id=804">Black Reaper (492|489) K44</a>  
<a class="ctx" href="#"></a></span>
```

All I want to do is get the address that links to and then use location. to go there.

Once again, apologies for my lack of prowess and thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do, is to select the `span`by his `class` and then finds the `a` tag you want.
So you can write this:

```
var linkhref = $(".village_anchor").find("a").first().attr("href");
```

Then, you can do the "redirection":

```
document.location = linkhref;
```

Comment: Thankyou so much - this does the job exactly as I wanted

Comment: @NewBee Thank him by accepting it as an answer if it solved your issue. He has put his time to help you out.

Comment: my apologies, I thought I had done that already but have done so now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
var address = $('span.village_anchor.contexted a:eq(0)').attr('href');

window.location.href = address; //to open the link in same page.
```

Comment: Here you are selecting all `a` tags. He's interested with only the first.